# Setting Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture suddenly seems to have no effect for me

Tags: c#, visual-studio, internationalization, visual-studio-2017, culture

We have a C# Click-Once application that uses Windows Forms (Yes, I know that is old, we will be creating a new application with Xamarin soon). There are a few of us, each developing in Visual Studio 2017. We share our code via TFS. I have all the latest Visual Studio updates installed and have compared my visual studio version, 15.2 (26430.16) with my co-workers. We have the same version.

Anyway, Our application is multi-user, users log in with separate accounts and we set the display language based on user-preferences, not the machine's current language. We set it using this line:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = OurFormClass.UserPreferredCultureInfo;
```

OurFormClass.UserPreferredCultureInfo is a static method that returns our user's preferred language in a CultureInfo object.

We have been doing this for years however a few days ago I noticed that it no longer works for me.  Strangely, it still works for the rest of our developers. When I log in as one of our foreign-language test-users all of my label controls and string resources are still in English.  I have set a breakpoint at the above line and it is getting set to the correct language however there is no effect.

I have tried deleting my source code and pulling it back down from source control.  This did not help. I even tried uninstalling and re-installing Visual Studio. This still did not help.  I copied my build output to a network drive and had one of my co-workers run it. Everything was English. I had him copy his build output to the network drive and I ran it. Internationalization worked!

I really don't know what to even try from here. I am using known-good source code and a fresh install of Visual Studio. Does anyone have any ideas where I should look next?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, but in a multithreaded application. Setting CurrentUICulture or CurrentCulture on a thread does not actually change the culture.